# Blender 2.76 file browser slow

Tags: file-browser

I recently tried the final release candidate of blender 2.76 and the file browser is extremely slow. Regardless of what opens the file browser, it will take 20-30 seconds to open up and freezes my blender until open. This did not happen in 2.75 as far as I'm aware and it seems 2.76 introduced an improved file browser.
I've tried empty scenes, different versions of 2.76, but nothing changes and It's really killing my workflow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't been experiencing that with 2.76. Is it always in the same directory? Maybe do some tests to see if browsing in a different location makes a difference. If you still have the 2.75 installation try to repeat the same steps within 2.75 just to confirm if it really is a version-specific issue. If you can produce a replicable symptom then submit a bug report.

Comment: I tried with blender 2.75 and the problem is very much the same, I must've not repeated the same steps as 2.76. It's an odd issue really.